# How do i get textfield value in nativescript

Tags: javascript, nativescript

i'm trying to get the text from my textfield in nativescript core.

```
let textField = args.object;
const yourSearch = textField.getViewById("requiredSkill").text;
```

the error i get is : **cannot read property 'text' of undefined**

please help

Comment: can you give more info, the html or the data, which framework is this, etc, please, also explain what is `args.object`

Comment: @DickensAS Its Nativescript

Comment: please confirm `args.object` is a click/tap event or text change event ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NativeScript View XML `TextView`

```
<TextView editable="true" id="requiredSkill"></TextView>
```

A simple button with `tap` event

```
<Button text="Button" tap="{{ onButtonTap }}" />
```

The JavaScript code behind for that tap event

```
var viewModel = observableModule.fromObject({
   onButtonTap: function (btargs) {
     let srcButton = btargs.object;
     const yourSearch =  srcButton.page.getViewById("requiredSkill").text;
   }
});
```

`getViewById` should be used on the `<Page>` model to search the entire page
or you must have a container/layout which should have an id, first find the layout using `getViewById` then again do another `getViewById` within that layout to find the `TextView`

so to answer your question, if it is a button click event, get the button and get the page of the button and find the view by Id

```
srcButton.page.getViewById
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Dickens , I am adding a specific example for [NativeScript playground](https://play.nativescript.org/):

**home-page.js:**

```
var HomeViewModel = require("./home-view-model");
var homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel();

function pageLoaded(args) {
  var page = args.object;
  page.bindingContext = homeViewModel;
}

exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

**home-page.xml:**

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded" xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
  <ActionBar title="Home">
    </ActionBar>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout orientation="vertical" width="210" height="210"
            backgroundColor="lightgray">
            <TextField id="uspas" hint="Enter text..."  text="aaa,bbb"/>
            <Button text="Login" tap="{{ login }}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Page>
```

**home-view-model.js:**

```
var observableModule = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");

function HomeViewModel() {
  var viewModel = observableModule.fromObject({
    login: function (buttonArguments) {
      let srcButton = buttonArguments.object;
      const testo = srcButton.page.getViewById("uspas").text;
      var uspasCouple = testo.split(",");
      us = uspasCouple[0];
      pas = uspasCouple[1];
      console.log("Hai scritto:", us, pas);
    },
  });

  return viewModel;
}

module.exports = HomeViewModel;
```